# Android app to disable lock screen security automatically

Tags: android, automation, lockscreen

I'm looking for an **Android app** that **automatically prevents the device** (phone or tablet) **to lock the screen** depending on a few circumstances:

- **Time**: the device is (going to be) in a "safe" area for mm minutes or until hh:mm
- **WiFi network**: the device is connected to a known, predefined, WiFi
  network.
- **Geographic position**: the device is within a circle centred
  in a particular location (given by GPS coordinates, i.e. latitude and longitude)

The app should be able to handle at least one of those situations; perhaps the one I'd be more interested in would be the one about time.

#### Use cases

For example, the app could give me the ability to save various WiFi networks on a list, and when this functionality is activated, it should automatically prevent the device to lock the screen if connected to one of the WiFi networks on the list.

This means **I wouldn't have to input my PIN to enter the home screen** of the device, in practice disabling whatever screen lock is configured. Note that after some inactivity I still want the screen to turn off, but when that happens, if I then press the power key the home screen should be displayed immediately without me typing the PIN.

Other use cases are pretty self-explanatory: the device should not ask me for the PIN until a target time is reached or if the device is within a circle of radius x centred on a specific latitude and longitude.

#### App type

I'd prefer a free/open source app, but I could also accept a paid app.

The app should work on non-rooted devices.

*First thought:* for those of you who know/use [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) or something similar, is it a tool that could help me to achieve what I'm asking for?

Comment: Did you read [this](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/better-way-disable-android-screen-lock-connecting-home-network/) ?!

Comment: @wingedpanther Thank you, I had a quick look at [Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama) and it's potentially really good. I'll try it as soon as I can and I'll let you know. In the meantime, whoever has other suggestions is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @wingedpanther's suggestion, I've found [Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama) to be great.

It's an app for **automation** that **can do much more than I was asking for**, in a clever way (see the list on the app page).

Basically with Llama one can create several different **events**, with **actions** triggered based on certain **conditions**. One of its strengths is that it uses **phone masts** (cell tower) to determine the location of the device: this is a great feature when it's required to create location-based events, especially for those that don't keep the GPS on all the time and live in populated areas (which have many cells).

For example, in one my use cases, I wanted to disable the Android lock screen whenever I'm in an area defined as *Home*, and then re-enable it when leaving that same area. I defined my *Home* area as made of two particular cells, then I simply created a couple of events:

- **No PIN**: it triggers a `Screen lock password` action based on the condition of *Enter/In* the *Home* area. Such password is set to empty/blank.
- **PIN**: it triggers a `Screen lock password` action based on the condition of *Leave* the *Home* area. Such password is set to the usual PIN already existing on my device.

[image: Llama PIN and No PIN events]

I've found that to be sufficient to me so far but, since it's part of my requirements, I would add that it's also possible to create **time-based events**, and there's an experimental feature to use **WiFi-based location tracking**.

The app is free, works on non-rooted devices and I recommend it to any Android power-user.